# Gallery load with ajax in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I use Cakephp 2.8.0. My problem is ajax. I don't know how realize ajax in my application. I have li links with categories and after click i need delete some html code and find in my controller necessary category and get this array in response html and print it.

my PhotosController action:

```
public function getPhotoByCategory($category = null)
{
    $category=$_GET['category'];
    debug($category);
    $this->render('getPhotoByCategory', 'ajax');
}
```

My html code:

```
 <div class="lol">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($categories as $category):?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['Category']['cat_name'];?>" class="lol"><?php echo $category['Category']['cat_name'];?></a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My JS code:

```
$(".lol").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',category,
        data: {catyegory:
        url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Photos', 'action' => 'getPhotoByCategory')); ?>',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.error) {
                alert(response.error);
                console.log(response.error);
            }
            if (response.content) {
                $('#target').html(response.content);
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Please, help me with right ajax in cakephp for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to handle AJAX for fetching items is to create an element of the items you want to insert (in your case photos from a category).

**PhotosController.php**

```
public function getPhotoByCategory($category = null)
{

    $this->set('photos', $this->Photo->find('all', ['conditions' => ['category_id' => $category]]);
    $this->render('Elements/getPhotoByCategory'); 
}
```

The element in the above example contains a for loop that loops through $photos and outputs them. This is then loaded into the div "lol" using the JS code down below:

**Views/Photos/get_photo_by_category.ctp**

```
<button class="loadphoto">Load Photos</button>
<div class="lol">
</div>
```

**JS Code (top of view?)**

```
$('.loadphotos').click(function(e) {
    $('.lol').load('/Photos/getPhotoByCategory/1')
    .fail(alert("error"));
});
```

Dereuromark has done some decent documentation on [AJAX and CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/)